# automated bash script execution using cron

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have been trying to use the cron package for scheduled bash script execution as is generally intended, and have found almost everything I need via this resource [here](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)

However the part I was unable to find, was the means for which I can set a beginning **and** end for a particular cron schedule to be **conditional**, ie I suppose I wanted a particular cron job to only be executed in march daily, and to then continue in april if say some binary variable (whose value is determined from some sort of assessment of the cron job's march output) is 1, and for the the cron job to be terminated until further notice if it's value is 0.

I apologise if my phrasing is unclear, constructive criticism is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this variable supposed to reside?

Comment: ok well what I had envisaged, which obviously hypothetical, I'm very new to things, was a separate cron schedule to perform the "evaluation" of the original cron job, and pipe the output to the "cron job continuity variable"

Comment: so I suppose it would need to be an environmental variable I would need to create which again is another learning process I'm in the middle of

Comment: @user535733 is this the kind of thing you are refering to? http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: You could arrange for the March cronjob to create (or delete) a file, and for the April cronjob to test for the file's presence (or absence) using `text -f /path/to/runfile && rest-of-your-cronjob` - kind of like how `/forcefsck` used to be used on reboot

Comment: sure for in the project I've set for myself, there is always a file generated, being a text file containing a list of IP addresses that appear in the output of cron scheduled tcpdump executions that were logged during march, and the other "output checking " cron job will either terminate the original cron job or execute it for april based on a statistical test

Comment: I mean I had to try and compile things into a project with a legitimate goal, simply because the sheer amount of things I don't know about Linux was getting a tad overwhelming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put variables in the crontab file, so you can have

```
EXECUTE_JOB=1
```

Then implement the condition with this /bin/sh construct

```
* * * * * [ "$EXECUTE_JOB" = "1" ] && your existing job here
```

Then, on April 1, you can adjust the value of that variable accordingly